# UWP C# load image with await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, uwp-xaml

I want to load all the images in the padg_load event, but if the number of the images are too many, some listview items will display the blank, so I need to refresh again manually, but that is not what I want.

how can I do to wait for the all images are loaded?

here is the code in the Page_load

```
 rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Decode2Info>(text);
 foreach (Decode1Info info in rootObject.decodes)
    {
      info.LoadImage();
    }

 collection = new ObservableCollection<Decode1Info>(rootObject.decodes);
 SListView.ItemsSource = collection;
 progressView.IsActive = false;
```

loadImage is a method in the class

```
 public async void LoadImage()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = 
            await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(imageName);
            this.ImageSource = new BitmapImage();
            FileRandomAccessStream stream = 
            (FileRandomAccessStream)await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            await ImageSource.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It since like the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject causes the strange thing, I put it into the Task, now it works which was mine expect.

```
 rootObject = await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Decode2Info>(text);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not awaiting your `LoadImage()` method, so they won't have completed by the time the code below the `foreach` executes.  Change that method to this (as you can't `await` a `void`)

```
public async Task LoadImage()
{
    // ...
}
```

and then this line

```
info.LoadImage();
```

to

```
await info.LoadImage();
```

Chances are also good you will gain by beginning all the required `LoadImage()`s first, letting them run concurrently, then waiting for them all to complete:

```
rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Decode2Info>(text);

List<Task> tasks = rootObject.decodes.Select(LoadImage);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```